# Text editor wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, text-editor

I have a question about a text editor. 
If you want to add a post on your wordpress website. you can do that with the text editor on your wordpress-admin-page.
I've set up my own system to add posts (newsarticles) to a website (without wordpress). 
At this moment i have to add them manualy in a database (phpmyadmin) but i was wondering if it was possible to create an editor (with some code). Setting things in italic/bold would be a lot easier then, for me and for the people who doesn't understand this.
I hope my question was clear.

Comment: For the italic or bold setting, you can use [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) for example. That's the editor WordPress uses. They also have a [how to](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Installation) on installing the editor. But getting your editor to save to database is a whole other chapter. That would require PHP/MySQL for example, and some custom coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try with CKEditor. Download it [here](http://ckeditor.com/) (Not for WP) and use it as a text editor outside Wordpress.